# Undefined variable in PHP after include

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, include, dropdown

I'm new to stackoverflow (as a member at least) and I have a question.
I'm also new to PHP by the way.

Thing is:
I want to dynamically fill a second dropdown list with entries based on a first dropdown list (I want to show cities based on a selected province).
I managed to get the selected province to an external PHP file with an AJAX call in Javascript. 
But when I include the external PHP file in my original PHP file, the variable of the external file is undefined. 
The AJAX call is fired with an onchange event on the first dropdown menu.

And maybe you can also help with how I use that variable to get the right content in the second dropdown. I've used a multidimensional Array for that.

HTML:

```
echo('<select name="provincie" id="provincie"       onchange="ProvinciePHP()">');


    foreach ($provincie as $provincies){
        echo ("<option> $provincies </option>");
    }
    echo ('</select>');


echo('<select name="stad" id="stad"> </select>')
```

PHP ARRAY:

```
$provincie = array(
    'Selecteer een provincie',
    'Drenthe',
    'Flevoland',
    'Friesland',
    'Gelderland',
    'Groningen',
    'Limburg',
    'Noord-Brabant',
    'Noord-Holland',
    'Overijssel',
    'Utrecht',
    'Zeeland',
    'Zuid-Holland',
);
$stad = array(
    'Drenthe'       => array("Assen", "Emmen", "Hoogeveen", "Meppel"),
    'Flevoland'     => array("Almere", "Biddinghuizen", "Dronten", "Lelystad"),
    'Friesland'     => array("Heerenveen", "Joure", "Leeuwarden", "Sneek"),
    'Gelderland'    => array("Apeldoorn", "Arnhem", "Nijmegen", "Zutphen"),
    'Groningen'     => array("Delfzijl", "Groningen", "Stadskanaal", "Veendam"),
    'Limburg'       => array("Maastricht", "Roermond", "Sittard", "Venlo"),
    'Noord-Brabant' => array("Breda", "Den Bosch", "Eindhoven", "Tilburg"),
    'Noord-Holland' => array("Alkmaar", "Amsterdam", "Haarlem", "Hilversum"),
    'Overijssel'    => array("Deventer", "Enschede", "Hengelo", "Zwolle"),
    'Utrecht'       => array("Amersfoort", "Breukelen", "Utrecht", "Zeist" ),
    'Zeeland'       => array("Goes", "Middelburg", "Terneuzen", "Vlissingen"),
    'Zuid-Holland'  => array("Alphen a/d Rijn", "Den-Haag", "Rotterdam", "Schiedam"),
);
```

Comment: seems to be missing a lot of code, and you get a php error? if so include it

Comment: You say it is undefined after include, I will assume it works when you are not using an include, so I'm guessing the problem is your not including the relative URL.

Comment: You need to show the Javascript that performs the AJAX call, and the script that it calls.

Comment: Hey guys, I tried, seems that there is something wrong....

Comment: @Bandouglas:
No because when I concat a string in the variable, the string part shows, but not the data coming from the AJAX call. The succes return to AJAX is good though, I test that with the alert in the code below. I think it has something to do with that I have to somehow reload that variable, because the variable is already loaded before the onchange event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getProvincie(){
var provincie = $('#provincie option:selected').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getprovincie.php",
    data: {data: provincie},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#stad').css('display','inline');
    },
    error: function(data) {

    }
});
```

}

```
//PHP page to where the AJAX call points:
<?php
$resultaat = $_POST['data'];

echo($resultaat);
```